# how to export all items in listbox to excel in vb

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, listbox

i'm using vb windows form.

I'm trying to export all items in a listbox1 to excel file using a button, but the problem that it export only the first item

i want to export all the listbox1 items

here is my code

```
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

    Public Class Form1
   Dim MsExcel As Excel.Application
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click
    MsExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    MsExcel.Workbooks.Add()

    MsExcel.Range("A1").Value = ListBox1.Items

    MsExcel.Visible = True
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: maybe I got that wrong, but wouldn't `ListBox1.List` be an 2D-array having all data (rows & columns)??? also if not using copy/paste with the clipboard you need to get the correct range to output to... having 10 rows and 2 columns you would need to output to `Range("A1:B10")` or better use `Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(10,2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to loop through the item and increment the row you print in :

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1
Dim oItem As Object
Dim OffS As Integer
Dim MsExcel As Excel.Application
Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click
    MsExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set Wb = MsExcel.Workbooks.Open("Path_of_File")
    OffS = 0
    For Each oItem In ListBox1.Items
        Wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(OffS, 0).Value = oItem
        OffS = OffS + 1
    Next oItem

    Wb.SaveAs
    DoEvents
    Wb.Close
    MsExcel.Visible = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works great .. May i ask you how to make it saves in a specific excel file.. not a new excel file

Comment: Just change `MsExcel.Workbooks.Add()` to `MsExcel.Workbooks.Open(Path_Of_The_Excel_File)` ;)

Comment: Or `Set` your `MsExcel.Workbooks.Add()` to a variable (object) and later use your variable with `.SaveAs` and `.Close False`

Comment: See the edit (@DirkReichel : You're so fast, I can't post my edit!^^)

Comment: taking my comment into account (and having only one column inside the listbox) you could use `Wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A"&ListBox1.Items.Count).Value = ListBox1.Items`... and throw the loop far away :D

Comment: @bod : Glad I could help! Take a minute to take the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour to see how to accept answer and use votes! ;)

Comment: @bod : Thanks for accepting my answer! Enjoy SO (now that you can vote too!)